# HR Forcing to submit documents prior to give offer

Tags: job-offer, human-resources, job-change, india

At first, I have received call from Company HR to asking if I am exploring new jobs and normal things about my carrier.

Then after confirmation, there were two rounds of interviews over phone and Skype (given the COVID situation). And I have been told that I am selected and they wanted to move forward.

In the salary discussion I have requested an amount which was on higher side to open negotiation and HR agreed over text message on phone but not in mail.

Suddenly I got mails to fill out documents of background checks and submit all salary slips, ID proofs, previous offer letters, salary revision letters without any offer letter or even provisional offer from company side.

I have ask if the salary I have asked is okay or not, but then the response I got is " You have not submitted any documents so we are not moving forward with you, you can look for other offers".

Is this in general that all documents required to submit without even giving confirmation whether candidate got selected or not and no remuneration letters.

In my experience this is first case I have came across.

Comment: Which country is this?

Comment: What do you want to get out of the situation?

Comment: @SolarMike it's in india

Comment: @Helena I would like to if this is general practice by HR.

Comment: I had to bring proof of all certificates etc to one interview, another I had to bring them during the first week - but neither were in India. India seems to have their own set of rules like leaving letters...

Comment: @SolarMike you're correct, during walk-ins we required to bring, as if selected , same day company will give provisional offer. but this is new for me

Comment: Hopefully you get an answer, but I don't know how useful it would be. It would appear they no longer consider you a candidate.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Knowing whether this is typical will be useful for all future interview situations; OP will know whether they should find this behavior suspicious or whether they should expect it.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: I am fine if they don't won't me as candidate, I will work harder for another, but sending text messages that you have cleared rounds and over mail that's something else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a common practice in Indian Software/IT companies. They do request for  such documents before releasing an offer.

And since, you have not submitted, they decided to move forward. Nothing surprising here. It was rude of them. We'll come across all kind of recruiters. Generally, if a recruiter is really interested, they would have positively responded.

Be glad that you have dodged a bullet. Time for you to move forward as well.

Comment: :- Well, Your correct

Comment: I wonder why that is? Here in europe I have never been asked for documents before receiving and offer. I would also never send anyone anything without having the conformation that they want to hire me. 
It is normal to send all documents before signing, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 5):

> HR Forcing to submit documents prior to give offer

This doesn't sound professional or friendly at all. I'd not want to work in a company of people like that.

> In the salary discussion I have requested an amount which was on higher side to open negotiation and HR agreed over text message on phone but not in mail.

and

> Suddenly I got mails to fill out documents of background checks and submit all salary slips, ID proofs, previous offer letters, salary revision letters without any offer letter or even provisional offer from company side.

These are clear red flags.

A general practise in many Indian IT and software development shops is to determine your compensation based on your previous compensation and how well the least possible hike over that fits within the budget set aside by the company. And it may not be determined based on the consideration that what you are demanding aligns well with the acceptable compensation for your skill and experience level or not.

You are well within your rights to not disclose your previous salaries and pay slips (but then the company may choose to rescind offer). However, it's recommended to **not share any documents** until you have an offer confirmation in hand and that too in writing. **It would be not advisable to go ahead with any verbal commitments**.

> Is this in general that all documents required to submit without even giving confirmation whether candidate got selected or not and no remuneration letters.

No, this is not general. You are not liable to provide any kind of documents and you should be cautions not to unless you have an offer from the company and that too in writing (either email or print). Like I said, it's not a good idea to go ahead with simply a verbal commitment. That's neither professional nor trustworthy.

Comment: :- Yes, I also asked some of my friends, They suggested the same to not to trust anything over text messages. I am not submitting anything until I get some confirmation.
Thank you for response.

Answer (score 1):

I have been attending virtual interviews lately and this is something that is trending within India. They do request for such documents even before releasing an offer.
With the onset of virtual interviews, identity checks have become a priority. They will be releasing an offer letter against your name and they need to know whether you are the same person who sat for the interview as well as you the same person having the same background who mentioned things during verbal discussions(MR/HR).
You can also monitor the authenticity of a company/person sending you invites for interviews. The "domain" name(the one after @ symbol within From Email address) should be helpful with this. Also try LinkedIn to search for the recruiter/HR who is sending you links for interviews from that company. Get urself acquainted with his details and then after a bit of research you will know whether you are on right track or not.